# ActiveMerchant. SSL error in test mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, paypal, activemerchant

I'm using [ActiveMerchant gem](https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant) for Paypal express checkout in my rails app.

I've deployed my project to production and I'm having an error message

> ActiveMerchant::ConnectionError (The SSL connection to the remote
>   server could not be established)

I don't have this error in development and in production I'm still using test mode.

My `config/initializers/active_merchant.rb`

```
ActiveMerchant::Billing::Base.mode = :test
::EXPRESS_GATEWAY = ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway.new(
    login: CONFIG['PP_USER'],
    password: CONFIG['PP_PASSWORD'],
    signature: CONFIG['PP_SIGN']
)
```

How can I fix this error without installing SSL for test mode?
Is it possible at all don't use SSL for Paypal Express Checkout?